# Cucumber Scenario Outline slow on iterating after a browser.close through Watir

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I've got a scenario outline in cucumber that validates a number of instances of the same Web site. It logs into the site, checks a few things then closes the browser ready for the next iteration.

Following cucumber convention I've put the url's, user Id's and pwds into an examples table. It works correctly in that it validates each site but, on the 2nd and subsequent iterations after the first browser close, it can take up to a minute to restart the browser. Doesn't sound like much of a performance hit but when you get into 100's of sites being checked, it all adds up.

I've replaced the ui based steps with a quick Web service check, just downloading the wsdl and this version has no lag at all making me think the delay is to do with the browser.close statement.

Anyone, had similar issues or could shed some light on this?

Comment: Do you really need to close the browser each time?  Could you not just clear the cache and reload the homepage?

Comment: I'll give that a go but not sure. Each of the sites is on a different test server and each authenticates through NTLM with a pop up for user id, password and domain.

Comment: I'd expect that all of the authentication would be stored in the cache so hopefully 'browser.cookies.clear' in your before hook will do the job just fine.

Comment: I'll give it a go when I'm back in the office tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Ok,I tried the cookie clear but that didn't work. I've tracked the delay down to how I'm starting the browser. I have to use a system(start #{args [:url]}) to start the browser, then a Win32ole send keys to enter the user and pwd. If I use the watir start or  goto statements, the login dialog is displayed but this then hangs watir (the statement never completes). On the 2nd iteration and onwards, the system (start... statement is what's slow.